# Windows Server 2016 updates failing

Tags: windows-server-2016

Over the past few days, updates have failed for Windows Server 2016. The two updates that it's trying to install during the failure are:

- Security Update For Exchange Server 2016 CU8 (KB4073392).
  2018-03
- Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4088787).

The updates appear to install successfully, then it tells me to reboot. Upon startup, the installation appears to finish, but then it tells me that the update failed and it rolls back. I've tried several times, including downloading and manually trying the cumulative update. Additionally, Exchange Server 2016 (OWA) on this same machine seems to have quit working about the time these updates first failed.

Event Viewer just has a 1603 which is a general error. The message in there also has this:

`Use the following link for instructions on turning on logging support: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=23127`

But that link is a dead end. Any suggestions to get logging working?

Other ideas?